# Getting Error in class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, hamburger-menu

i am developing an application in android in which i want to implement hamburger menu. i am developing in mac os using eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and using `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` library.support design library and support appcompat library are also have same version and

i am getting this error message :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.demohamb/com.example.demohamb.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

please give me some demo example of hamburger menu.

**@MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.inbox:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                case R.id.starred:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stared Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.sent_mail:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Send Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.drafts:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drafts Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.allmail:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Mail Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.trash:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trash Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.spam:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Spam Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

            }
        }
    });

    // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


}
```

**@activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
     app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
     app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    />
```

**@LogCat Error message**

> 06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.aa/com.example.aa.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 06-09 15:08:21.777:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-09 15:08:21.777:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-09 15:08:21.777:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28914): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 06-09 15:08:21.777:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   com.example.aa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  ... 11 more 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 06-09 15:08:21.777:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    ... 22 more 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914): Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:96)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:166)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:95)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  ... 25 more 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView" on path:
>   DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.aa-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.aa-2,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 06-09 15:08:21.777:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552) 06-09
>   15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
>   06-09 15:08:21.777: E/AndroidRuntime(28914):  ...

Answer (score 2):

This problem will likely occur when the version of your **appcompat** library and **design support library** doesn't match.

Example

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' // appcompat library

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' //design support library

So check your build.gradle file and try to match those files.

Hope it will help.

Comment: i am working in eclipse, support design library and support appcompat library are also have same version.